# Matplotlib distributing the markers on a semilogx plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, slice

I want to plot a curve on a semilogx scale in Matplotlib. I have two vectors `fpr` and `tpr` of size 17874. I want to show markers on the same curve. But since there are too many points, I used `markevery=0.1`, as shown e.g. in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/markevery_demo.html) from the matplotlib page. However, using markevery in this case did not have any markers in the semilog plot (right panel):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, marker='o', markevery=0.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.semilogx(fpr, tpr, marker='o', markevery=0.1) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then, I tried to use slice object. As you can see in the plot below, the markers in the left plot are evenly distributed, but in the right semilogx plot, the markers are only shown in half of the curve. So I am wondering if there is any way to have a variable slice interval that can fix this issue.

[image: ROC plot on a normal scale and the semilogx]

My curent code is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, marker='o', markevery=slice(0, 20000, 1000))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.semilogx(fpr, tpr, marker='o', markevery=slice(0, 20000, 1000))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already gone through that link. For some reasons using float numbers for my case did not add any marker at all. For example, I tried markevery=0.1, but then the curve did not have any marker.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will update the question.

Comment: Well, this is not really a [mcve]. What data do I need to put in as `fpr, tpr`? This is crucial here, because your code and the matplotlib example only differ by the data used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion would be that the value in the data which seems close to zero actually *is* zero. Since the logarithm of zero is undefined, that point cannot be plotted on a logarithmic scale. Missing the first point in the graph though would not allow to calculate the spacings for `markevery`. (Just as in *"Calculate the mean of `NaN` and `1`"* , which is impossible.)

A solution is of course to leave out that point, which cannot be plotted anyways when calling the plot function for a log scale.

```
plt.semilogx(fpr[1:], tpr[1:], marker='o', markevery=0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight you gave me on this. You were absolutely right. The first 30 points were zero, so once I removed them, markevey=0.1 worked nicely.  plt.semilogx(fpr[30:], tpr[30:], marker='o', markevery=0.1)